# Determine if a couple of zip codes are contiguous

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My customer has sales regions where each sales region consists of a list of zip codes.
The regions are pretty big and could be easier stored in format like :

Region consists of zip code range from 00602 to 10012 and 20020 to 30020.

How can I get from a list of zip codes to a list of such zip code ranges?

**Consider the following data**

```
--This would be my list of all available zip codes in us:

CREATE TABLE [Zip](
    [Zip] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [State] [nvarchar](50) ,
)

--This would be the Sales Region List

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalesRegion](
    [AreaCode] [nvarchar](50) 
) 

--This would be the original large list Zip Codes for the SalesRegions

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EnteredZip](
    [Zip] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [AreaCode] [nvarchar](50) 
) 

--This is where I would like to store the Zip Code Ranges

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SearchableZip](
    [StartZip] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [EndZip] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [AreaCode] [nvarchar](50) 
) 

--Here is my sample Data:

--Some Zip Codes in US
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00501'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00544'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00601'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00602'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00603'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00604'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00605'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00606'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00610'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00611'   ,'PR')
insert into dbo.Zip (Zip,[State]) values ('00612'   ,'PR')


--Some Sales Regions

Insert Into dbo.SalesRegion ( AreaCode ) values('Area1')
Insert Into dbo.SalesRegion ( AreaCode ) values('Area2')
Insert Into dbo.SalesRegion ( AreaCode ) values('Area3')


--The zip codes of the Sales Regions
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00544' , 'Area1')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00601' , 'Area1')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00602' , 'Area1')

insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00604' , 'Area2')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00606' , 'Area2')

insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00501' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00544' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00601' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00602' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00603' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00604' , 'Area3')

insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00610' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00611' , 'Area3')
insert Into EnteredZip (Zip,AreaCode) values ('00612' , 'Area3')
```

Would result in this entries in the table SearchableZip

```
AreaCode             StartZip             EndZip
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------------
Area1                00544                00602
Area2                00604                00604
Area2                00606                00606
Area3                00501                00604
Area3                00610                00612
```

Is it possible to create SearchableZip with a sql script?

**EDIT**

I fixed the table declaration and output data

Comment: The `insert into EnteredZip …` statements are inconsistent. They do not match the table's declaration, and the column values are in the wrong order.

Comment: If you have a performance problem, this isn't the way to solve it. Edit your question, and paste the query execution plans for the queries that aren't performing well. As it stands, it looks like you're guessing at a solution. Guessing doesn't scale well.

Comment: You are right about that.But I have to try it.Even if it is a bad way (which it realy might be)

Comment: Well, no, you *don't* have to try restructuring your tables *now*. You can post the query execution plans. That's absolutely the most reliable way to resolve a performance problem on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to obtain the ranges from the list with a single query. For that you will use a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), [ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx), and a bit of [grey matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_matter):

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    Zip,
    AreaCode,
    ZipGroup = CAST(Zip AS int)
             - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AreaCode ORDER BY Zip)
  FROM EnteredZip
)
SELECT
  StartZip = MIN(Zip),
  EndZip   = MAX(Zip),
  AreaCode
FROM ranked
GROUP BY AreaCode, ZipGroup
```

Output:

```
StartZip             EndZip               AreaCode
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------------
00544                00544                Area1
00601                00602                Area1
00604                00604                Area2
00606                00606                Area2
00501                00501                Area3
00544                00544                Area3
00601                00604                Area3
00610                00612                Area3
```

This output doesn't match yours, but it does match the source data.

---

**UPDATE**

If the Zip table is a reference table for determining the contiguity of a list of zip codes, then the above solution should be modified like this:

```
WITH ZipRanked AS (
  SELECT
    Zip,
    State,
    ZipRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY State ORDER BY Zip)
  FROM Zip
),
EnteredZipRanked AS (
  SELECT
    e.Zip,
    e.AreaCode,
    ZipGroup = z.ZipRank
             - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.AreaCode ORDER BY e.Zip)
  FROM EnteredZip e
    INNER JOIN ZipRanked z ON e.Zip = z.Zip
)
SELECT
  StartZip = MIN(Zip),
  EndZip   = MAX(Zip),
  AreaCode
FROM EnteredZipRanked
GROUP BY AreaCode, ZipGroup
```

Comment: The output in the sample data is correct now. The query you gave cant work because the table Zip is necessary. For instance the Area1 has StartZip 00544 and Endzip 00602, because there exists no other zip code between these two codes then 00601.Sry for making this harder then necessary by giving the wrong input data.

Comment: I understand the point, although the Zip table in your sample doesn't contain the `00601` zip code, which is present in the entered zip code list. Is this possible in a real-life situation or did you just omit the code by mistake?

Comment: Beautifull! I just had to remove "e.AreaCode = z.State AND". The state in the Zip table doesnt have a meaning for my query.

Answer (score 0):

First, I need to tell you that what I *think* you're planning to do strikes me as a bad idea. The table EnteredZip is just fine for storing which area a ZIP code belongs to. (As long as you put a PRIMARY KEY constraint on ZIP.)

It looks like this is roughly where you're aiming,

```
select areacode, min(zip), max(zip)
from enteredzip
group by areacode
order by areacode
```

but it doesn't match your output. Frankly, your sample output doesn't make sense to me.

There's only one row for Area1, but the ZIP codes aren't contiguous. There are two rows for Area2, but each has a single ZIP code. There are two rows for Area3, but the ZIPs aren't contiguous.

Wait . . .

Does *contiguous* mean you inserted a blank line between the INSERT statements in the sample data?

If that's the case, then you need to store more data. You have to identify which ZIP codes should be considered contiguous, and store those facts in a table. (Also, you left out a blank line in Area2.)

Comment: I edited the sample output to be more easy to read.I see the point you make about not being a good idea.I just want to try if it solves my performance problem.Maybe I have a chance if the regions are realy big.Indexes are already in place but that wasnt enough.